# Why do these identical Unicode strings have different serialized forms?

Tags: r, serialization, character-encoding

When I compare a string literal with a non-ASCII character in R source code to the same string passed in through the command line, the two strings test as `identical` and have identical `charToRaw` representations, but `serialize` differently. What's going on? Aren't both strings in UTF-8?

To reproduce this, try this shell script (I'm running Dash 0.5.10.2-7 and R 4.0.2 on Ubuntu 20.10):

```
echo 'x="α"' > program.R
R --vanilla -q -e \
'source("program.R")
print(identical(x, "α"))
print(identical(charToRaw(x), charToRaw("α")))
print(identical(serialize(x, NULL), serialize("α", NULL)))'
```

which produces

```
> source("program.R")
> print(identical(x, "α"))
[1] TRUE
> print(identical(charToRaw(x), charToRaw("α")))
[1] TRUE
> print(identical(serialize(x, NULL), serialize("α", NULL)))
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: Not sure if it is the problem, but equivalent Unicode strings may be written in different ways. Unicode tell us to treat them equally (e.g. in `identical`), but you may want to preserve the original form (so different serialize). Normalizing unicode strings is often a good way to avoid surprises. [e.g. order of accent, composition/decomposition, or different way to use composition + accent, and much more]. Or you are using different characters (similar or equal on screen), see https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/confusables.jsp?a=fast+forward+labs&r=None for different "alpha"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might show what's going on

```
echo 'x="α"' > program.R
R --vanilla -q -e \
'source("program.R")
y="α"
.Internal(inspect(x))
.Internal(inspect(y))'
```

which for me gives

```
> .Internal(inspect(x))
@558f4edc1630 16 STRSXP g0c1 [REF(3)] (len=1, tl=0)
  @558f4edc15f8 09 CHARSXP g0c1 [REF(1),gp=0x20] [cached] "α"
> .Internal(inspect(y))
@558f4edd3860 16 STRSXP g0c1 [REF(2)] (len=1, tl=0)
  @558f4edd3898 09 CHARSXP g0c1 [REF(3),gp=0x28,ATT] [UTF8] [cached] "α"
```

So the values of `x` and `y` are different. I'm not an expert on all these values, but the `gp=` values are showing the string attributes. Those differences are what are resulting in the serialization differences. As far as I can tell, the string you set when you source the file has an undetermined encoding. It is not assumed to be UTF-8. If when you `source()` the file you specify the encoding explicitly, then the serializations will be the same.

So when I run

```
echo 'x="α"' > program.R
R --vanilla -q -e \
'source("program.R", encoding="UTF-8")
print(identical(x, "α"))
print(identical(charToRaw(x), charToRaw("α")))
print(identical(serialize(x, NULL), serialize("α", NULL)))'
```

I get

```
> print(identical(x, "α"))
[1] TRUE
> print(identical(charToRaw(x), charToRaw("α")))
[1] TRUE
> print(identical(serialize(x, NULL), serialize("α", NULL)))
[1] TRUE
```

Thus, replacing `source("program.R")` with `source("program.R", encoding="UTF-8")` makes the last check come out `TRUE`. Similarly, you can add `x <- enc2utf8(x)` or `Encoding(x) <- "UTF-8"`.